# Migration in Postgresql and Django 1.8

Tags: django, database, postgresql, python-2.7

In my project I am using django 1.8 and for a fresh project if I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it shows the following message:

**You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.**

Then if i run the command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

it works fine for sqlite.
But if i connect with postgresql in my local_settings.py and run the above migration command then it gives the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an app that has a (generic) foreign key to `ContentType`. This causes migrations to fail because the database tries to create a foreign key to a table that doesn't exist yet. Try migrating `contenttypes` first with `python manage.py migrate contenttypes` and then applying your other migrations.